# Why do 2 .col divs stack on top of each other and how to repeat this on the opposite side in boostrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
.box1,.box2,.box3,.box4,.box5,.box6, .box7 {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.box1 {
    padding: 140px 10px 0 10px;  
    background: #000 url("../img/...") center center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 250px;
}

.box2 {
    padding: 71.6px 10px 0 10px;  
    background: #000 url("../img/...") center center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.box3 {
    padding: 71.6px 10px 0 10px;  
    background: #000 url("../img/...") top center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-sm-12 box1">
           <h3>Here is Heading for Box1</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-sm-12 box2">
          <h3>Here is Heading for Box2</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-sm-12 box3">
          <h3>Here is Heading for Box3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    

<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12 box4">
          <h3>here is the heading</h3>
        </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12 box5">
          <h3>here is the heading</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12 box6">
          <h3>here is the heading</h3>
        </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12 box7">
          <h3>here is the heading</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the link to the Wish Pic for the layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwVw3.jpg

As you can see in the attached picture, I am looking to create a layout with 2 rows in Bootstrap.

I have been able to create the first row - but I cannot get the second row layout to work. I am struggling with .box4 and .box5 being on top of each other while both being on the left of .box6.

Although now I have no idea how, as you can see from the attached code, I have been able to make the upper row work (having .box2 on top of .box3).
I have been trying to disect the code over the last few days and I am really struggling as to how the first row is working and the second one isnt.

Any help is much appreciated.

****Please note****
- .boxNumber classes are given in addition to .col classes for further styling purposes.
- There are .col classes within .col classes because of the spacing in between the boxes (columns) / for styling purposes.
- I have added a border to each box for visualisation purposes

Please preview the embedded conde on a screen with width larger than 768px.

If someone might be able to tell me how the first row is working I might be able to figure out the second row.

Comment: Rather than posting the code, if you could embed your code snippet here or maybe a jsFiddle/plunkr snippet, it'll be easier to debug :)

Comment: @PraveenSingh Apologies as this is the first time I was posting here - the code has been embedded now. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you. [Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

```css
.box1 {
  background: red;
}
.box2 {
  background: lightblue;
}
.box3 {
  background: yellow;
}
.box4 {
  background: teal;
}
.box5 {
  background: black;
}
.box6 {
  background: blue;
}
.box7 {
  background: grey;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-6 box1">
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-lg-12 box2">
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 box3">
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col-md-12 box4">
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 box5">
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col-lg-12 box6">
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col-lg-12 box6">
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response! I believe the second .box6 is meant to be .box7 - I am also not sure why you are using 2 .container-fluids and have the .box1(.col-sm-6) outside a .row class.

Comment: I have been looking at that link - Grid System on BS for days but only after seing how you nested cols within a col I figured how I can implement my layout. Though I have to admit, I am still not sure how the first row is working within my code snippet as I have not followed this method of nesting there. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need two containers, that was just to separate the two for the example and essentially you want the first (Box1) outside the row because of the way bootstrap adds padding and because it's alone (not nested like the rest of the row. Please don't forget to mark you question as answered so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarificaiton. I can now create the desired output via nesting but I am still not sure as to how the first row is working without nesting. Would you know by any chance or should I just start a new post simply for that?

Comment: The very first col-sm-6 doesn't need to be inside a row with the nested columns because a standard column is what your format calls for. If you put it inside that row you'll see what I'm saying regarding padding. It will 'break' your formatting. You needed a column for half the grid as your first block and split/nested blocks for the other half.